# Creating a hopscotch game to see if it is solvable or not solvable in c

Tags: c

Suppose you are given the following numbers:
4 4 1 5 2 6 3 4 2 0

The number, with a square around it, indicates where you are currently standing.  You can move left or right down the line by jumping the number of spaces indicated by the number you are standing on.  So if you are standing on a 4, you can jump either left 4 spaces or right 4 spaces.  You cannot jump past either end of the line.

For example, the first number (4) only allows you to jump right, since there are no numbers to the left that you can jump to.

The goal:  you want to get to the 0 at the far end (right side) of the line.  You are also guaranteed that there will be only one zero, which, again, will be at the far right side.

You are to write a recursive function that returns an integer 1 (for solvable) or 0 (for not solvable), indicating if you are able to get to the rightmost 0 or not.

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward. The algorithm is known as a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: Key phrase there: `You are to write...` -- which means not us!

Answer (score 0):

> You are to write a recursive function that returns an integer 1 (for solvable) or 0 (for not solvable), …

[Recursion (computer science) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_functions_and_algorithms) is a good start:

> A recursive function definition has one or more *base cases*, meaning input(s) for which the function produces a result trivially (without recurring), and one or more *recursive cases*, meaning input(s) for which the program recurs (calls itself).

The base cases are:

- jump outside of the given line of squares → return 0
- arrived at the square with number 0 → return 1

The recursive case is:

- return (solvable for jumping to the right OR solvable for jumping to the left)

A short C code for this:

```
int hops[] = { 4, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 0 };
#define DIM(a)  sizeof a / sizeof *a

int solvable(int square)
{
    if (square < 0 || DIM(hops) <= square) return 0;    // past an end
    if (hops[square] == 0) return 1;                    // got to the 0
    return solvable(square+hops[square]) || solvable(square-hops[square]);
}
```

The initial call is starting from the square with index 0: `solvable(0)`.